# Insert a variable in pre_get_posts

Tags: pre-get-posts

I've searched in google with no luck. I'm trying to add a variable into this code to modifiy the category of the posts in homepage:

Code Not Working:

```
<?php $p = $_GET ['p'] ;?> 
<?php $catvar = get_cat_ID($p); ?>
<?php function my_home_category($query) {$query->set('cat', $catvar);}add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_home_category' );?>
```

Code Working:

```
<?php $p = $_GET ['p'] ;?> 
<?php $catvar = get_cat_ID($p); ?>
<?php function my_home_category($query) {$query->set('cat', 25);}add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_home_category' );?>
```

When I manually put the id of the category the code is working and I only see the posts of that category.
Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: Where is that `$p` coming from ?

Comment: From here <?php $p = $_GET ['p'] ;?> I get the p value from the url: http://localhost/?p=category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use a variable inside a function which has been defined outside the function!
Get the value from `$_GET` inside the function.

```
function my_home_category($query) {
    if (isset($_GET ['p'])) {
        $catvar = get_cat_ID($_GET ['p']);
        $query->set('cat', $catvar);
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_home_category' );
```